# Iterating over a mutli-dimensional array with PHP seems to be skipping over values

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to PHP, only using it for a class, and I am trying to iterate over a multi-dimensional array. For some reason, the foreach I am using seems to skip over every other position in the array.

Here is the array I am iterating over:

```
define('TAX_RATES',
    array(
        'Single' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35, 39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0, 9275, 37650, 91150, 190150, 413350, 415050),
            'MinTax' => array(0, 927.5, 5183.75, 188588.75, 46278.75, 119934.75, 120529.75)
        ),
        'Married_Jointly' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35, 39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0, 18550, 75300, 151900, 231450, 413350, 466950),
            'MinTax' => array(0, 1855, 10367.5, 29517.5, 51791.5, 111818.5, 130578.5)
        ),
        'Married_Separately' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35, 39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0, 9275, 37650, 75950, 115725, 206675, 233475),
            'MinTax' => array(0, 927.5, 5183.75, 14758.75, 25895.75, 55909.25, 65289.25)
        ),
        'Head_Household' => array(
            'Rates' => array(10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35, 39.6),
            'Ranges' => array(0, 13250, 50400, 130150, 210800, 413350, 441000),
            'MinTax' => array(0, 1325, 6897.5, 26835, 49417, 116258.5, 125936)
        )
    )
);
```

And here is how I am iterating through the array:

```
echo '
<div class="container">
    <h2>2016 Tax Tables</h2>';
foreach (TAX_RATES as $status => $inner) {
    echo '<h4>'.$status.'</h4>'.'
<table class="table table-striped>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Taxable Income<th>
            <th>Tax Rate<th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>'.money_format('%10n', $inner['Ranges'][0]).' - '.money_format('%10n', $inner['Ranges'][1]).'</td>
            <td>'.$inner['Rates'][0].'%'.'</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';
}
echo '
</div>';
```

This is the output I am getting:
[image]

See how it is skipping over Married_Jointly and Head_Household?

This is what I am trying to produce:
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I know I'm not through with building all of the table entries.

If I get rid of the table, it seems to iterate over all of the filing statuses just fine:

```
echo '
<div class="container">
    <h2>2016 Tax Tables</h2>';
foreach (TAX_RATES as $status => $inner) {
    echo '<h4>'.$status.'</h4>';
}
```

[image]

I'm really at a loss as to what's going on here.

Comment: The code works fine for me [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92e3800e0ee75895c61762082f22f8cf29a9b1e4)  Make sure your array is truly  what you think it is.  `print_r(TAX_RATES);`

Comment: Just a syntax error. Missing double quote after classes here: `<table class="table table-striped>`

Comment: change this `echo '<h4>'.$status.'</h4>'.'` to `echo '<h4>'.str_replace('_', ' ', $status).'</h4>'.'` ... it was bugging me ... and what they said ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is correct. It is your resulting HTML markup that is broken, resulting in elements present in source but omitted visually in output:

```
<table class="table table-striped>
```

Should be:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
```

Missing a closing quote.